# finding a basis of tensor product of dual space

Tags: differential-geometry

Let  $U$ and $V$ are two vector spaces and $U^*$ and $V^*$ are respective  dual spaces . Let {$e^i:1\le i \le n$} and {$a^j:1\le i \le n$} are bases for $U^*$ and $V^*$ respectively . Then author says that since $\otimes$ is bilinear , we have 
$$  u^*\otimes v^*= \sum _{i,j}u^*(e_i)v^*(a_j)e^i \otimes a^j$$ 
where {$e_i$} and {$a_j$} are the bases of $U$ and $V$ respectively.therefore , for any velement of $U^* \otimes V^*$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $e^i \otimes a^j$ and {$e^i \otimes a^j,1\le i \le n, 1\le i \le n $} are linearly independent.

here $U\otimes  V$ is the tensor product of two vector spaces.

---

but I can not understand these points that is how it is become a linear combination and how the set {$e^i \otimes a^j,1\le i \le n, 1\le i \le n $} becomes linearly independent.

---

Can someone explain it elaborately please.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ have basis $\{ e_i \}$ which has dual basis $\{e^i \}$ of $U^*$. Likewise, Let $V$ have basis $\{ a_i \}$ which has dual basis $\{a^i \}$ of $V^*$. To say these are dual is to insist that $e^i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ and $a^i(a_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Consider $b: U \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ( I assume your vector spaces are over the real numbers) a bilinear form. Let $x = \sum_i x^ie_i$ and $y =  \sum_j y^j a_j$ then, by bilinearity and the Lemma (see below)
\begin{align} b(x,y) &= \sum_i \sum_j x^iy^j b(e_i,a_j) \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j b(e_i,a_j)e^i(x)a^j(y) \\
&= \left( \sum_i \sum_j b(e_i,a_j)e^i \otimes a^j \right)(x,y) 
\end{align}
Thus, any mapping from $U \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is linear in both "slots" can be expressed as a linear combination of the tensor product of the dual bases $e^i \otimes a^j$.

Linear independence follows from supposing $\sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}e^i \otimes a^j =0$. This is a functional equation. To prove $c_{kl}=0$ simply evaluate at $(e_k,a_l)$. I begin with the left hand side,
\begin{align} 
\sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}e^i \otimes a^j(e_k,a_l) &= \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}(e^i \otimes a^j)(e_k,a_l) \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}e^i(e_k) a^j(a_l) \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} \\
&= c_{kl}
\end{align}
On the right hand side of $\sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}e^i \otimes a^j =0$ the $0$ denotes the zero map from $U \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and so $0(e_k,a_l)=0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we obtain $c_{kl}=0$ for all $k,l$ and it follows that $\{ e^i \otimes a^j \}$ forms a linearly independent set of real-valued bilinear maps of $U \times V$.

**Lemma:** if $x = \sum_i x^ie_i$ then $x^i = e^i(x)$.

**Proof:** 
$$e^j(x) = e^j(\sum_i x^ie_i) = \sum_i e^j( x^ie_i) = \sum_i x^i e^j( e_i)=\sum_i x^i \delta_{ij} = x^j.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response.But can you please tell me what is the procedure of calculating $(e_k,a_l)$

Comment: I haven't shown it, but $T \otimes S$ is bilinear on $U \times V$. We feed a pair $(e_k,a_l)$ to a function on $U \times V$. For the tensor product of maps, $T \otimes S(e_k,a_l) = T(e_k)S(a_l)$ by definition of $\otimes$. I assume you view tensor products as represented by multilinear maps.